# How can I Set Xaml code behind property from it's own XAML. e.g "this"

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have my Xamarin forms MasterDetailPage Xaml code-behind .xaml.cs file where I created a string property.

I want to set that property from the front-end Xaml.
I know it seems like a newbe question, but for crying-out-loud I can't get anything to work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

E.g.

this.stringProperty = "string" IN XAML markup.

Or pseudo-code

{RelativeSource Self}.stringProperty ="string"

Thanks

@TRS

Let me clarify by using your code. I only need the first part of your code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window <-- YOUR CODE
{

   private testString;  <-- ADDED THIS

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyClass(); <-- REMOVED THIS

    public string TestString;    <-- ADDED THIS
    {
        get => testString;  
        set
        {
         testString;   = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to set the "TestString" property from this same partial class's MainWindow XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
x:Name="Mywindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

SET TestString PROPERTY IN THE CODE BEHIND HERE IN THE XAML
```

So, with that in mind. How can I do it?

Comment: you have to use bindings just google for dataBinding. You will need to create DependecyProperties ind your datacontext for this to work. This can be your code behind but thats not recommended if you want to follow a MVVM pattern

Comment: See my answer to @TRS

Answer (score 0):

Here is minimal working example for you .But you have to read about DataContext, INotifyPropertyChanged and MVVM to understand it thoroughly,otherwise you will have many questions.Keep you code behind clean.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Mywindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}"></TextBlock>

</Grid>
```

and code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyClass();
    }
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myString;

    public string MyString
    {
        get => _myString;
        set
        {
            _myString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```